# How to passing two id's from the URL to the controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm sorry I can't pass two ids from the URL to the controller give me an error  Undefined variable: id

the problem in the user id in the controller

My Route:

```
Route::get('addappotouser/{id}/{dates_id}','UsersController@create');
```

Href :

```
<a href="{{url('addappotouser' . '/'. $usersss->id .'/'. $date->id)}}" value="" class="btn btn-success btn-mini deleteRecord" type="submit">{{$date->Dates}}</a>
```

Controller:

```
 public function create( $id , $dates_id)
{
      $bookappoitm=DB::table('times')


          ->where('times.Dates_id',$dates_id)

       //  ->where('times.Dates_id',1)


         ->whereNoTIn('times.id',function($query){

           $query->select('times_id')->from('bookappoitments')
          ->where('users_id',$id) 

         ->get();

     })


   ->get();


   $datee=Dates::find($dates_id)
   ->where('dates.id',$dates_id)
    ->select('dates.*')
    ->first();


    $userss=User::find($id)
    ->where('id',$id)
    ->select('users.*')
    ->first();

     return view('admin.Managers.addappotouser', compact('bookappoitm','datee','userss'));
```

URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/addappotouser/1/1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code with this you need to use `$id` like this

```
$bookappoitm=DB::table('times')->where('times.Dates_id',$dates_id)->whereNoTIn('times.id',function($query) use ($id){

       $query->select('times_id')->from('bookappoitments')
        ->where('users_id',$id) 
        ->get();
     })
     ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need pass the parameters as array, see https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-route,

```
<a href="{{url('addappotouser', [$usersss->id, $date->id])}}" value="" class="btn btn-success btn-mini deleteRecord" type="submit">{{$date->Dates}}</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay but it still gives me the error Undefined variable: id

Comment: ->where('users_id',$id)   in the user id $id

Comment: You are not passing `$id` in `whereNoTIn('times.id',function($query)`.

Comment: Yes ! you need to pass $id inside your function, your code indentation is poor.

Comment: Could you please help me how to pass it, sorry I'm new in this

Comment: See my answer and tell if this help.

Comment: @HimaHima, see rouhollah and Muhammad answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helping now it's working for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the line as below:

```
->whereNoTIn('times.id',function($query) use ($id){
```